# Send null value to sql via axios post

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, axios

I have a very simple question. I want to send null value to MySql server using axios.post method. The value is defined as an int in the sql table. I have tried passing null but nothing happens. I have also tried passing '' but I end up with 0. I validated that any random int will work by passing random integers with no problem. I really need to make it null though. How can I do this?
This sends nothing...

```
    axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/update-air", 
    {airValue: null}).then(() => {
        alert("Successfull")
    })
```

This sends 0...

```
    axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/update-air", 
    {airValue: ''}).then(() => {
        alert("Successfull")
    })
```

This sends 100...

```
    axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/update-air", 
    {airValue: 100}).then(() => {
        alert("Successfull")
    })
```

I need it to change an int back to null by literally sending null as a value.

server side code...

```
app.post("/api/update-air", (req, res) => {
    const airValue = req.body.airValue;
    const sqlUpdateAir = "UPDATE user SET airValue=(?) WHERE uid='j' ";
    db.query(sqlUpdateAir, (airValue), (err, result)=>{
        console.log(airValue);
    })
```

Comment: show a route on a server side and code that saves a value to a DB

Comment: I edited my original post with this included at the bottom. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: What value do you have at this line `const airValue = req.body.airValue`?

Comment: if I use null it is null, ' ' it is 0, and 30 is 30 or any other random int. but it is not pushing to mysql when null. All others do.

Comment: I thought I fixed it but realized it wasn't pushing values to server still. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: Do you have a NOT NULL constraint for this column in DB?

Comment: Nope. It is simply defined as an INT.

Comment: Did you try to execute manually this script with `null`?

Comment: I think you are asking if I tried on mysql server, and yes it works. If i enter this...     UPDATE user SET waterValue=NULL WHERE uid='j'     it will insert null

Comment: Ok, now try ` db.query(sqlUpdateAir, null`

Comment: Nope, same result. I was looking at the documentation for axios and it may not be possible to do what I am trying, which seems kind of weird. There must be a workaround for this as it is probably no uncommon.

Comment: If  `db.query(sqlUpdateAir, null` has the same result then axios is not your issue. Look at docuentation of `db.query`

Comment: OMG I found the error. So simple. Solution is below.

Answer (score 0):

null needs to be wrapped in an array [] when queried. so replace this...

```
db.query(sqlUpdateAir, null, (err, result)=>{
    console.log(airValue);
})
```

with this...

```
db.query(sqlUpdateAir, [null], (err, result)=>{
    console.log(airValue);
})
```